# Не удается применить стиль к первому абзацу

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

Сайт на wordpress и есть у меня бокс с описанием, в котором необходимо строку с составом и весом блюда опустить на 70px. Возможности вмешаться в код html нет, текст может быть разным кроме первого абзаца и я не уверен насчет того, в какой последовательности он появляется: после применения стиле или до, т.к. запись

```
.product-section>p:first-child {
  margin-top: 70px;
}
```

не спасает, а если убрать `:first-child`, то стили применяются ко всем тегам `p`. Как быть?

```css
.product-section>p:first-child {
  margin-top: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-section">
  <h3><a href="#">Пицца «Мы самые вкусные»</a></h3>

  <div class="rating-box">Рейтинг</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <p><strong>Состав и вес блюда</strong>
    <br>Состав: <em>лапша яичная, курица, чеснок, лук, соевый соус, индийский орех</em>
    <br>
    <strong>Порция</strong>: <em>150г.</em>
  </p>
  <hr>
  <strong>Калорийность</strong>
  <br>
  <em>Белки(100г): 11,49г.</em>
  <br>
  <em>Жиры(100г): 22,32г.</em>
  <br>
  <em>Углеводы(100г): 32,33г.</em>
  <br>
  <em>Энерг. ценность(100г): 368,39калл.</em>
  <p></p>
  <span class="title-description"></span>
  <br>
  <img src="" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: И слишком меток вы много ставите. Тут если только `css` надо оставить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант

```css
.product-section div.clear + p {
  margin-top: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-section">
  <h3><a href="#">Пицца «Мы самые вкусные»</a></h3>

  <div class="rating-box">Рейтинг</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <p><strong>Состав и вес блюда</strong>
    <br>Состав: <em>лапша яичная, курица, чеснок, лук, соевый соус, индийский орех</em>
    <br>
    <strong>Порция</strong>: <em>150г.</em>
  </p>
  <hr>
  <strong>Калорийность</strong>
  <br>
  <em>Белки(100г): 11,49г.</em>
  <br>
  <em>Жиры(100г): 22,32г.</em>
  <br>
  <em>Углеводы(100г): 32,33г.</em>
  <br>
  <em>Энерг. ценность(100г): 368,39калл.</em>
  <p></p>
  <span class="title-description"></span>
  <br>
  <img src="" alt="">
</div>
```

**UPD**
Ниже IE9 жизни нет:

```css
.product-section p:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-section">
  <h3><a href="#">Пицца «Мы самые вкусные»</a></h3>

  <div class="rating-box">Рейтинг</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <p><strong>Состав и вес блюда</strong>
    <br>Состав: <em>лапша яичная, курица, чеснок, лук, соевый соус, индийский орех</em>
    <br>
    <strong>Порция</strong>: <em>150г.</em>
  </p>
  <hr>
  <strong>Калорийность</strong>
  <br>
  <em>Белки(100г): 11,49г.</em>
  <br>
  <em>Жиры(100г): 22,32г.</em>
  <br>
  <em>Углеводы(100г): 32,33г.</em>
  <br>
  <em>Энерг. ценность(100г): 368,39калл.</em>
  <p></p>
  <span class="title-description"></span>
  <br>
  <img src="" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: да уж, не супер изящный способ на clear надеяться, но пока работает - спасибо

Comment: @Вася, дополнил ответ.

Comment: а вот так да, красивее получается